# Prove that a function is positive semi-definite

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I am given this function $$\phi(t) = (1+|t|)e^{-|t|}$$ and asked to prove that it is a characteristic function for a certain random variable. Bochner's theorem says that the main condition a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ needs to satisfy for this is being positive semi-definite, which means that for any $t_1,...,t_n$, the $n\times n$ matrix where $a_{ij} = \phi(t_i-t_j)$ is PSD.

I have tried to bound the expression $z^{T}\mathbb{\Phi}z$, where $z\in\mathbb{C}^n$ from below somehow but failed. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You could always try Fourier inversion, and calculate what the density of the variable should be.

Comment: Bochner's theorem is a theoretically useful result rather than practically. For this function $\phi$ you just need to take the Fourier transform and check that the result is $\ge0$.

Comment: can I just ask how checking that the result is non-negative suffices? I tried doing the inverse Fourier on the given function in order to get something resembling a pdf, but the resulting integral is pretty terrifying to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\phi(t)=(1+|t|+kt^2)\exp(-|t|)$ is a characteristic function for $0 \leq k \leq 1/4$ according to the Theorem 1.2 from the following paper:

Gneiting T., *Kuttner’s problem and a Polya type criterion for characteristic functions*, Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 128 (2000),1721–1728.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not a answer.